# Don't get json data in PHP web service

Tags: php

I am writing my first Javascript/PHP Web application. 
On the client side I am using the below code:

```
<script>
$.ajax({
  url: "Search.php",
  type: "POST",
  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
  dataType: "json",
  data: '{SubGroup:"'+SubGroup+'",FlowerColor:"'+FlowerColor+'"}',
  cache: false,
  success: function (data) {
      console.log("Back from AJAX - Success.");
      // $(document).ajaxSuccess implements the success logic
  },
  error: function (data) {
    console.log("Back from AJAX - Error.");
  }
});
```

The Web Service Search.php runs perfectly with one major issue. The data sent from the ajax statement (SubGroup and FlowerColor) are not received. I am using the code below.

```
<?php 
if (isset($_POST["SubGroup"])) {
    $SubGroup = $_POST['SubGroup'];
} else {
   error_log("Invalid input Received (SubGroup)");
   exit;
}
```

Strangely enough i am receiving the rest of the header information perfectly with the below code:

```
 // Getting headers sent by the client.
 $headers = apache_request_headers();
 foreach($headers as $key => $value)
 {
      error_log($key . ' = ' . $value);;
 }
```

Comment: Did you try to `console.log(data)`?

Comment: Please don't try to create your own json string. Create an object, then send it back as is or with [`JSON.stringify()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify).

Comment: Can you try with return statement in web service Search.php ?.. ```return "error";```

Answer (score 0):

If you pass data as a string, it should be URL-encoded, and not a string representation of JSON : `SubGroup=...&FlowerColor=...`

You can also pass you data as an object :

`data: {SubGroup: 'mygroup', FlowerColor: 'mycolor'}`

From the [JQuery Doc](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

> processData (default: true)
>
> Type: Boolean
>
> **By default, data passed in
> to the data option as an object (technically, anything other than a
> string) will be processed and transformed into a query string, fitting
> to the default content-type "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"**. If
> you want to send a DOMDocument, or other non-processed data, set this
> option to false.

Comment: Thanks Joffrey. I believe the problem for me was two folds: (1) trying to send data as a sting  and not as you suggested. (2) type: "POST" somehow is not working for me, Switching to "Get" did the trick.

Comment: So the final working code looks like: 
  $.ajax({
      url: "Search.php",
      type: "GET",
      contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
      dataType: "json",
      cache: false,
      data: {"SubGroup": SubGroup, "FlowerColor": FlowerColor},
      success: function (data) {
          console.log("Back from AJAX - Success.");
          // $(document).ajaxSuccess implements the success logic
      },
      error: function (data) {
        console.log("Back from AJAX - Error.");
      }
  });